# I want to drag and drop the image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I want to drag the **image** on canvas and it should be dragging again inside canvas when dropped i have done some work i have completed dragging of **navbar** and **buttons** and **divs**  .I am attaching my fiddle please check,
I tried lots of thing but could not  find any solution to resolve this issue.

```
my fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Yousuf_007/d3tyrwp6/

Comment: So what is the issue ?

Comment: issue is  now i want to drag and drop image same as i done for navbar and buttons, But it is not happening i tried lots of things.In my fiddle you will understand when you try yo drag and drop the image and other element.please try @manikat gautam

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `img` tag with `div`

```
<div class="fake tool button ">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg" alt="W3Schools.com" style="width:104px;height:142px;" class=" tool-1">
</div>
```

I updated your example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d3tyrwp6/1/)

EDIT:

If you don't want to wrap the `img` with `div` change

```
var handle = $("<div>", {
              class: "tool_handle ui-widget-header"
            })
```

to

```
var handle = $("<div>, <img>", {
              class: "tool_handle ui-widget-header"
            })
```

This is the updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3tyrwp6/2/)

Comment: good solution really good  !!! but i dont want to wrap  image in divs. if it is possible for you   please try to do without div so it is draggable by  <img> tag.   thanx your favor will be  highly appreciated.

Comment: i added another solution without warping the img

Comment: why it is stop dragging inside canvas after drop???  anyway  thankx alot sir. thank you so much